# How to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with

Tags: node.js, npm

Windows, VSC, Running `npm start` got this

> npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe but npm is using
>   C:\somewhere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe
>   itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the
>   path for the node binary npm was executed with.

I understand it means my local version is diff from the one in the PATH variable (C:\Program Files...). How do proceed to tell it to use `--scripts-prepend-node-path`?

I played a trick by replacing the `C:\Program Files\nodejs` with `C:\somewhere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin` in PATH variable, it does pick up that new node.exe got `but there is no node binary in the current PATH`. Again recommend to use the `--scrip
ts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Like I said, replacing the actual path in PATH system variable didn't fix the problem completely, it still complained about binary is missing. Found [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000644114-Node-js-Run-Script-option-doesn-t-work-no-node-binary-in-the-current-PATH) solved the `there is no node binary in the current PATH` problem. So I restored the original PATH, then:

> Simply create a file at the root folder of the app, called **.npmrc**,
> place this line into it:
>
> `scripts-prepend-node-path=true`

Comment: Not sure why, but this worked for me, but the `npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path auto` command answer below didn't. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to add on that this still works as of July 2021.

Comment: This option has been removed in recent npm: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2808

Answer (score 134):

Here's another way that works: `npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path auto`

Comment: Since the issue seems to happen across different projects, this is the preferable answer, so you don't need to create a .npmrc file in each project, which is what the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: Accepting this as the Accepted Answer since a) it works (in all of my environments) and b) as @kas pointed out, it makes life easier.

Answer (score 33):

## Conflict between your Node Binary and your NPM

---

In case the error looks something like:

> npm is trying to use the same node as the one it use to run itself.

Resolve this conflict by adding the node directory to your `PATH`:

```
npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path true
```

[From the npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> npm run sets the NODE environment variable to the node executable with
> which npm is executed. Also, if the --scripts-prepend-node-path is
> passed, the directory within which node resides is added to the PATH

Answer (score 9):

Having this issue in Visual Studio 2017, I instead told VS to always use the NodeJS that I had installed from nodejs.org rather than the frozen-in-time one that ships with Visual Studio. (The one that shipped with VS2015 is so ancient it doesn't really work anymore.)

In Visual Studio, go to TOOLS > OPTIONS > search for EXTERNAL WEB TOOLS > and ensure "C:\Program Files\nodejs" (or wherever nodejs.org installed it) is first in the list of paths, adding it if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

For WebStorm, invalidating caches and restarting worked for me.