# How to fix BINARY ERROR when deploying a Node Js API REST to CPANEL. (shared hosting)

Tags: node.js, npm, cpanel, shared-hosting, dev-to-production

first of all thanks for the help.

I have a Node js API REST, i use Express, fs module, sharp for images and many others, everything works fine in my machine, and i wanted to test this API in a shared hosting that i purchased months ago.

i have my app in my folder, the node js create app from CPANEL Recognizes my JSON file, when i click NPM INSTALL this is the error that comes up:

```
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/webfoqgo/nodevenv/server/12/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
ERR! sharp Use with glibc 2.12 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.10.0
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
make: execvp: cc: Permission denied
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.77.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/webfoqgo/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.19.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN building-backend@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.26.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.26.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/webfoqgo/.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T20_32_15_794Z-debug.log
```

i tried 2 things:

1.- i made a .npmrc file in my project root like this:

[image: Please let me know if i am doing this incorrectly]

2.- i deleted the SHARP dependency from my package.json -- this makes the process of NPM INSTALL in cpanel go well, no error, but do need sharp in my project so deleting it is not a viable option for production.

Links that i have checked:
[StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293566/how-to-include-the-path-for-the-node-binary-npm-was-executed-with)

have anybody came across this sometime?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but as soon as I deleted the environmental variables and hardcoded them the error disappeared. I had to do it because it doesn't seem to be possible to include a .npmrc file in CPanel.